# How to do this SQL in Entity Framework?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

```
SELECT * 
FROM geoip_blocks 
INNER JOIN geoip_locations ON geoip_blocks.geoname_id = geoip_locations.geoname_id
WHERE network >>= '5.39.25.176'::inet;
```

How do this with Entity Framework? `context.geoip_blocks`?, Preferably without using raw SQL